# Get the percentage of a value between two values

Tags: java, max, min, percentage

I have a minimum value and a maximum value (The values can change).
I also have a value that is in between of these two values.

```
private int minValue = 201;
private int maxValue = 500;
private int currentValue = 482
```

Now I need to get the percentage of the currentValue between 0% and 100%.
Is this even possible?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: what do you mean by "percentage of the currentValue between 0% and 100%" ?

Comment: yes it is, it´s the same caluclation as you would do it on a paper and calculate it.

Comment: The percentage is just the `currentValue / maxValue` in this case `96.4%`. The `minValue` has no influence on the overall percentage

Comment: Do you not know how to code an arithmetic expression in Java, or you don't know yow to calculate a percentage?  Google.

Comment: @m_callens it actually shouldn´t or? it should be `(curr-min)/(max-min)`.

Comment: @amphibient i mean that the calculated percentage has to be between 0% and 100%. 101% would not work with my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want to have is this calculation:

```
double percentage = (currentValue - minValue) / (maxValue - minValue);
```

Just like @kevin-esche wrote in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

If minValue is 201 and maxValue is 500, then the full range is 500 - 201 = 299, then if currentValue is 482:

```
    ((currentValue - minValue) / (maxValue - minValue)) * 100
    =((482 - 201) / (500 - 201)) * 100
    =(281 / 299) * 100
    =93.97993
```